# laminas authentication - redirect to login page when using a listeneraggregate

Tags: php, laminas

I am migrating an app from ZF2/3 to Laminas. I have moved the authentication from the Module.php bootstrap, to an aggregatelistener, and would like to redirect to a login page if the user is not logged in for certain routes. This worked fine originally, but i am having trouble after the migration - it is now redirecting 20 to 30 times and causing a "page is not redirecting properly" error.

My Module.php onBoostrap method:

```
class Module implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * @param $event
     */
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
    {
        /** @var ApplicationInterface $application*/
        $application = $event->getApplication();

        /** @var TemplateMapResolver $templateMapResolver */
        $templateMapResolver = $application->getServiceManager()->get(
            'ViewTemplateMapResolver'
        );

        // Create and register layout listener
        $listener = new LayoutListener($templateMapResolver);
        $listener->attach($application->getEventManager());

        //Create and register Authentication listener
        $authenticationListener = new AuthenticationListener();
        $authenticationListener->attach($application->getEventManager());
    }
}
```

The AuthenticationListener class:

```
class AuthenticationListener extends AbstractListenerAggregate
{
    /**
     * @param EventManagerInterface $events
     * @param int $priority
     */
    public function attach(EventManagerInterface $events, $priority = 1)
    {
        $this->listeners[] = $events->attach(
            MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH,
            [$this, 'userHasAuthentication']
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param MvcEvent $event
     */
    public function userHasAuthentication(MvcEvent $event)
    {
        $authenticationService   = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get(AuthenticationService::class);
        if($authenticationService->hasIdentity() === false){
            $event->stopPropagation(true);
            // ? how to redirect
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I have tried the following approaches to redirecting, and these still end up with the "not redirecting properly" result.
Inside AuthenticationListener::userHasAuthentication:

```
if($authenticationService->hasIdentity() === false){
    $event->stopPropagation(true);
    /**@var AbstractActionController $target*/
    $target = $event->getTarget();
    return $target->redirect()->toRoute('auth.login');     
}
```

...or...

```
if($authenticationService->hasIdentity() === false){
    $event->stopPropagation(true);
    /**@var AbstractActionController $target*/
    $target = $event->getTarget();
    $response = $target->getResponse();
    $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Location', '/login');
    $response->setStatusCode(403);
    $response->sendHeaders();
    return $response;     
}
```

What is the correct way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you get redirection loop, cause this listener is also triggered on /login page. You have to check the current route before redirecting.

```php
public function userHasAuthentication(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $routeMatch = $e->getRouteMatch();
    if ($routeMatch) {
        $routeName = $routeMatch->getMatchedRouteName();
        if ($routeName !== 'login' && $routeMatch->getParam('loginRequired',true)) {
            $auth = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get(AuthenticationServiceInterface::class);
            if ($auth->hasIdentity() === false) {
                $response = new \Laminas\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response();
                $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Location', "/login");
                $response->setStatusCode(302);
                return $response;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Adding condition on route param 'loginRequired' allows you disable redirection for chosen paths adding `'loginRequired'=>false` in 'defaults' section in route config.

BTW, if you use higher listener priority, or attach it do `MvcEvent::ROUTE`, you can display login page on every path by changing route match

```php
public function userHasAuthentication(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $routeMatch = $e->getRouteMatch();
    if ($routeMatch) {
        $routeName = $routeMatch->getMatchedRouteName();
        if ($routeName !== 'login'
            && $routeName !== 'logout'
            && $routeMatch->getParam('loginRequired', true) !== false
        ) {
            $auth = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get(AuthenticationServiceInterface::class);
            if ($auth->hasIdentity() === false) {
                $routeMatch->setParam('controller', LoginController::class);
                $routeMatch->setParam('action', 'login');
                if ($routeName !== 'home') {
                    $e->getResponse()->setStatusCode(401);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On loginAction add

```
if ($this->auth->hasIdentity()) {
    $this->checkTourDismiss($this->auth->getIdentity());
    if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
        && !in_array($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ['/', '/login'])
    ) {
        $this->redirect()->toUrl($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    } else {
            $this->redirect()->toRoute('home');    
    }
}
```

in the end, so after logging in user stays on URL he started with.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should've added, that the authentication is only used on the back end - a different module to the main application, which has no auth requirement. Also, the authentication looks up the current route and checks it against a blacklist, which the login route is not included in. I haven't read all of your answer yet, so will check the rest of your answer in more detail.

Comment: i have just tested it, and you are right - the auth call is being applied to the login page too.

Comment: Accepted answer, thanks for the advice. I thought it was only the all the config arrays that were merged, not the behaviour of the config class itself. A little confusing to be honest, as my main site /application config class doesn't define the listener, so i assumed it would not be applied to that.

Comment: I understand the issue now. Each module that needed authorisation before any of the controllers could be accessed were using the SharedEventManager in each modules onBootstrap, using the modules __NAMESPACE__ as an identifier. The ListenerAggregate used above uses the normal EventManager, hence why it was being triggered for every module. 

Is it possible to use a ListenerAggregate with a SharedEventManager? The interfaces used do not seem to allow it.